# Why does my kivy window sometimes feel laggy and later begins to feel normal again?

Tags: user-interface, kivy

Why does my kivy window sometimes feel laggy and later begins to feel normal again?

I am using windows 10, kivy version 1.11.1 and python version 3.7.6. I used anaconda to install kivy and before running the file, I activate the conda environment.

While the python file is running, this text is logged to the terminal.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Umar\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-09-05_21.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "F:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "F:\anaconda3\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4425'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.00 - Build 10.18.10.4425'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

I restarted my laptop but the problem persists. This problem has occurred before but was resolved without doing anything.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Why does my kivy window sometimes fell laggy and later begins to feel normal again?

Comment: Oh I see, the text you posted is not something you're suggesting is related to the error? In that case it sounds like the app is doing something in the background that is taking up rendering time. Does this happen even for simple Kivy examples?

Comment: Sometimes even more complicated applications work and sometimes even less complicated application don't work. I don't understand anything about this behaviour.

Comment: By work, I meant work smoothly